# How to finish this proof about $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\Omega$ be a countable set and $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.
>
> Prove that there exists some countable partition of $\Omega$ that spans $\Sigma$.
>
> That is, prove the existence of $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a partition of $\Omega$ and $\displaystyle\Sigma=\{\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j\;|J\subset \mathbb N\}$ .

Here is my attempt.

Define an equivalence relation $R$ over $\Omega$ as follows: $$xRy := \forall A\in \Sigma, x\in A \iff y\in A$$

Let $B$ be the set of equivalence classes of $R$.

$B$ can be trivially injected in $\Omega$, and is therefore countable.

Set $B=\{A_n\; | n\in \mathbb N \}$.

It remains to prove that $\displaystyle\Sigma=\{\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j\;|J\subset \mathbb N\}$.

I managed to prove that $\displaystyle\Sigma\subset\{\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j\;|J\subset \mathbb N\}$, but the reverse inclusion stumped me.

Note that it suffices to prove that $\forall n, A_n \in \Sigma$.
To prove that, I tried to go for contradiction, but I end up intersecting a **non-necessarily countable** infinite number of elements of $\Sigma$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to prove that $A_j \in \Sigma$.

Suppose $A_j = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots\}$, then $\exists B_1 \in \Sigma$ such that $A_j \subset B_1$. Suppose $\{y_1, y_2, \cdots \}$ are elements in  $B_1 $ that are not in $A_j$, then for each $y_n$ we can either find $C_n \in \Sigma$ such that $y_n \in C_n$ but all $x_n$'s are not in it, or find $D_n \in \Sigma$ such that all $x_n \in D_n$ but  $y_n$ is not in it

So $A_j = B_1 \bigcap_n C_n^c \bigcap_n D_n$
where one of $C_n$ and $D_n$ is trivial

So, for a countable underlying space, any $\sigma$-algebra is countably generated.

Comment: Nice try but your argument is flawed : "for each $y_n$ we can find $C_n∈Σ$ such that $y_n∈C_n$ but all $x_n$'s are not in it." needs not be true. You didn't negate the definition of "$xRy$" properly, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @G.T.R I think it's ok, unless I've missed something :). It's exactly but your definition of equivalence class that we can find such $C_n$, because if we can't find such $C_n$, then $y_n$ is in the equivalence class of $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots \}$

Comment: Nope, only the following holds: $\exists C_n\in \Sigma, [A_j \subset C_n\setminus \{y_n\} \;\text{OR} \; y_n\in C_n\setminus A_j]$

Comment: @G.T.R Got your point, thanks. How about now? I've edited

Comment: I had the same thought last night, but I think that when writing $B_1 \bigcap_n C_n^c \bigcap_n D_n$ you don't get rid of all the $y_n$, but only of those that are in some of the $C_n$

Comment: @G.T.R when I can find a such $C_n$, I mean $D_n = \Omega$, when I can find such a $D_n$, I take $C_n = \emptyset$. Then $y_n$ is not in $C_n^c \cap D_n$, but all $x_n$ are in it, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, well done :) I got one last objection: how do you know that "$\exists B_1 \in \Sigma$ such that $A_j \subset B_1$ " ?

Comment: Ah, my bad, of course $A_j \subset \Omega$

Comment: And there you go, over 6000 points !

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary, and fix $x\in A_n$. If $y\in\Omega\setminus A_n$, there is an $S_y\in\Sigma$ such that $A_n\subseteq S_y\subseteq\Omega\setminus\{y\}$. Since $\Omega$ is countable, ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really don't get why $A_n\subseteq S_y\subseteq\Omega\setminus\{y\}$ is true, and how to use it next. Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: @G.T.R: $y$ is not equivalent to $x$, so some $S_y\in\Sigma$ contains $x$ but not $y$. Everything in $A_n$ *is* equivalent to $x$ and therefore must be in $S_y$. Now intersect the $S_y$ with $y\in\Omega\setminus A_n$; what do you get, and how many members of $\Sigma$ have you intersected?